# How to make a navbar like WikiHow?

Tags: html, css

I would like a navbar like WikiHow with a icon on top and text beneath. I have been taking a look at their code but it seems pretty messy and I think there is easier ways to do it.

**CSS**

```
nav ul li{
    border-left: 1px solid red;
    height: 80px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70px;
} 

.nav_icon{
    margin-top: 15px;
    background: url('inc/icon.png');
}
```

**HTML**

```
<nav>
     <ul>
        <li><div class="nav_icon"></div>HOME</li>
        <li>PICTURES</li>
        <li>ABOUT</li>
    </ul>   
</nav>
```

Then I created a `<div>` that I inserted before "HOME" in the first `<li>` element. I put some `padding-top: 15px;` on the div to make it go down a bit, but affects the whole `<li>` elements. I just want the icon to get some margin from the top...

http://jsfiddle.net/JmZbG/1/

Comment: Might want to set up a demo. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Play with this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/88Uq4/).

Answer (score 0):

By default inline blocks will align based on their text baseline.

Just add `vertical-align: top;` to the CSS for `nav ul li` to have them align by their top edge instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version: http://jsfiddle.net/JmZbG/2/

And here's an explanation of the changes:

```
nav ul li {
    border-left: 1px solid red;
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 80px; /* Center the labels vertically */
    float: left; /* Another way of lining up the <li>s horizontally */ 
    display: inline-block;
}

.nav_icon {
    display: inline-block; /* Needs to be an inline-block to be inline with the text */
    vertical-align: middle; /* This centers the image vertically in it's <li> */
    width: 46px; /* Need to define a size for an empty <div>... */
    height: 41px; /* ...in order to see the background image */
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/mDXvZOZ.jpg");
}
```