# How to make a navbar like WikiHow? Continued

Tags: css

I want a navbar like WikiHow (with a picture on top and text beneath) and when the mouse is hovering the button I want the icon to change to another icon. But how do I manage that?

So basically when the button is hovered I want the image to change to another image.

http://jsfiddle.net/JmZbG/3/

```
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `:hover` with an other image that you want. I picked 1 from google, just for the example.

```
li:hover .nav_icon {
    background: url('http://enews.cityyear.org/customer_images/32/wordpress-icon-small.jpg');        
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JmZbG/10/)**

Comment: Nice! And i saw my prefious code worked fine to? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575825/how-to-make-a-navbar-like-wikihow/20577302#20577302